# How to create 2-element combinations of characters in a nested list in R?

Tags: r, loops

I've got a list-of-lists (cat_uniqueval_list) of several categorical variables, shortened here for simplicity:

```
country <- c("Rwanda", "Ghana", "Nigeria", "Malaysia")
sex <- c("M", "F")
lifestyle <- c("farmer", "hunter-gatherer", "fisherman")

cat_uniqueval_list <- list(country, sex, lifestyle)
names(cat_uniqueval_list) <- c("country", "sex", "lifestyle")
```

I'd like to create a new nested list, called cat_2combo_list, where each sub-list (country, sex, lifestyle) contains every 2-element combination possible. For example:

```
cat_2combo_list[[1]]

[[1]]
[1] "Rwanda"  "Nigeria"

[[2]]
[1] "Rwanda" "Ghana" 

[[3]]
[1] "Rwanda"   "Malaysia"

[[4]]
[1] "Nigeria" "Ghana"  

[[5]]
[1] "Nigeria"  "Malaysia"

[[6]]
[1] "Ghana"    "Malaysia"

cat_2combo_list[[3]]

[[1]]
[1] "farmer"  "hunter-gatherer"

[[2]]
[1] "farmer" "fisherman" 

[[3]]
[1] "fisherman"   "hunter-gatherer"
```

Here is my code so far. The issue is that even though this produces the result I want for the first variable, country, the elements of "sex" and "lifestyle" are identical to the results of "country"; in other words, each sub-list contains the same 6 combinations of Rwanda, Ghana, Nigeria and Malaysia. This is set up in a loop because in reality I have more than 20 variables that would be tedious to go through one-by one.

```
x <- cat_uniqueval_list # original nested list
cat_2combo_list <- foreach(
  i=seq_along(x), # iterate through every sublist (i)
  .final = function(i) setNames(i, names(x))) %do% { # retain names from original nested list (x)
    tryCatch({
      y <-  do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(i), function(i) combn(x[[i]], m=2, FUN = list))) # for every sublist (i), create a new list that contains every 2-element combination of x[[i]] elements
      },
      error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance for any advice!

Comment: `lapply(cat_uniqueval_list, combn, 2L)` if you want the result to be a list of wide matrices; `lapply(lapply(cat_uniqueval_list, combn, 2L), t)` if you want the result to be a list of long matrices; `lapply(cat_uniqueval_list, combn, 2L, simplify = FALSE)` if you want the result to be a list of lists.

Comment: Perfect and elegant, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A combination of functions from the `tidyverse` should do the job. Here you have a reprex. And I like it, because it is pretty short.

```r
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(tidyverse)))

country <- c("Rwanda", "Ghana", "Nigeria", "Malaysia")
sex <- c("M", "F")
lifestyle <- c("farmer", "hunter-gatherer", "fisherman")

cat_uniqueval_list <- list(country, sex, lifestyle)
names(cat_uniqueval_list) <- c("country", "sex", "lifestyle")

cat_uniqueval_list %>%
  purrr::map(~ tidyr::crossing(col_1 = .x, col_2 = .x))
#> $country
#> # A tibble: 16 x 2
#>    col_1    col_2   
#>    <chr>    <chr>   
#>  1 Ghana    Ghana   
#>  2 Ghana    Malaysia
#>  3 Ghana    Nigeria 
#>  4 Ghana    Rwanda  
#>  5 Malaysia Ghana   
#>  6 Malaysia Malaysia
#>  7 Malaysia Nigeria 
#>  8 Malaysia Rwanda  
#>  9 Nigeria  Ghana   
#> 10 Nigeria  Malaysia
#> 11 Nigeria  Nigeria 
#> 12 Nigeria  Rwanda  
#> 13 Rwanda   Ghana   
#> 14 Rwanda   Malaysia
#> 15 Rwanda   Nigeria 
#> 16 Rwanda   Rwanda  
#> 
#> $sex
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   col_1 col_2
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 F     F    
#> 2 F     M    
#> 3 M     F    
#> 4 M     M    
#> 
#> $lifestyle
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   col_1           col_2          
#>   <chr>           <chr>          
#> 1 farmer          farmer         
#> 2 farmer          fisherman      
#> 3 farmer          hunter-gatherer
#> 4 fisherman       farmer         
#> 5 fisherman       fisherman      
#> 6 fisherman       hunter-gatherer
#> 7 hunter-gatherer farmer         
#> 8 hunter-gatherer fisherman      
#> 9 hunter-gatherer hunter-gatherer
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Greetings, M.